# How to obtain last string after right-most space

Tags: sql, oracle

Dataset looks like this

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | Apple Banana |
| Corn | Corn Chips |

I would want "Banana" returned from the first row and "Chips" returned from the second row.

I've done (instr (Column B, ' ', -2)

This gives me the location of the space

I know I need to use a substr in conjunction with this, but for substr I need to specify the length of characters I want to retrieve right? How do I overcome the problem where the length of characters after the last space is different each time?

Answer (score 1):

> I know I need to use a substr in conjunction with this, but for substr I need to specify the length of characters I want to retrieve right?

No, if you do not specify the number of characters then the [`SUBSTR` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SUBSTR.html#GUID-C8A20B57-C647-4649-A379-8651AA97187E) will return the rest of the string.

So you can use:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(column_b, INSTR(column_b, ' ', -1) + 1) AS last_word
FROM   table_name;
```

To get the substring after the last space.

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Column_A, Column_B) AS
SELECT 'Apple', 'Apple Banana' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Corn',  'Corn Chips'   FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| LAST_WORD |
| --- |
| Banana |
| Chips |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bMSpJZeT)

Answer (score 0):

A *simple* option is to use regular expression, by fetching one or more occurrences `+` of a word `\w` which is anchored to the end `$` of the string.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (cola, colb) as
  2    (select 'apple', 'apple banana' from dual union all
  3     select 'corn' , 'corn chips'   from dual
  4    )
```

Query begins here:

```
  5  select cola, colb,
  6    --
  7    regexp_substr(colb, '\w+$') last_word
  8  from test;

COLA  COLB         LAST_WORD
----- ------------ ------------
apple apple banana banana
corn  corn chips   chips

SQL>
```